# const arrow function can't access imports

Tags: meteor, reactjs, react-router

Why is User not defined in the springboard function?
springboard is called `onEnter` in a React router Route.

```
import User from '/imports/api/user.js';

const springboard = (nextState, replace, callback) => {
    console.log(User.get());
}
```

Snippet from User:

```
User = {
  get: function() {
    return Meteor.user() || {};
  },
  …
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to export the object that you want to import:

```
export default {
  get: …
```

Note that the name of the exported object doesn't matter. You can give it any name, e.g., `User` when importing.